# Which software contains Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.dll?

Tags: visual-studio, ms-office

Is this dll a part of visual studio tools for office or Microsoft Office Word s/w?

Comment: It's distributed as the "Primary Interop Assemblies" and (depending on what you're doing) you might be looking for a Redistributable version of those, e.g. [Here thay are for 2007](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=18346)

Comment: It is *automatically generated* when you add a COM reference to "Microsoft Word xx.x Object Library".  Used to be part of the Office PIA but they are obsolete since .NET 4/VS2010, replaced by the vastly superior Embed Interop Types feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PIAs are just intermidiate files that are used in transferring/marshalling calls between mananged/unmanaged boundaries. For example, they are used to convert managed types to unmanaged ones. You can generate them on your own without VS involved. Under the hood, VS uses the same tools to generate them when you add an unmanaged references (COM).

You can read more about PIAs in the [Office Primary Interop Assemblies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/15s06t57.aspx) section in MSDN.